# The graph in C # GDI or zedgraph

Tags: c#, gdi, zedgraph

Need to draw a graph of all, a grid made ​​with the help of GDI +, the problem now draw a graph. As it is easier to do with GDI +? Or is it possible to construct a graph on my grid with zedgraph?

Answer (score 1):

I used to do a lot of GDI+ stuff but for graphing, Zedgraph is definately the way to go. I only used some of its functionality but found it easy to use. I used it to make a virtual oscilloscope.